# Callgrind chronological log of functions called

Tags: c++, logging, valgrind, trace, callgrind

I would like to obtain a chronological log of the functions invoked by a C++ program, preferably in a text file, using valgrind.

For the example C++ program (simple.cpp) below:

```
void baz(){
}

void bar(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    baz();
}

void foo(){
  bar();
}

int main(){
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

I wish to obtain
`main() -> foo()-> bar->baz()*3`

What I have tried:

Compile as `g++ -g simple.cpp -o simple.out`
and run `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./simple.out` to obtain `callgrind.out.3519`

Running `callgrind_annotate --tree=both callgrind.out.3519 | grep baz` returns nothing.

Saying `kcachegrind callgrind.out.3519` and then navigating within the source code view for the function `main()` allows me to see the calls in chronological order.

Is there a way to write just this information out to a log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like callgrind_annotate is meant to do exactly this with the data generated by callgrind. The reason it does not show "baz" given the trivial example is simply that your test code executes so quickly that the execution time spent within it pales in comparison to the time spent within the overhead code (e.g. dynamic-library loading code).

You can get callgrind_annotate to include your baz either by using the threshold parameter:

```
callgrind_annotate --threshold=100 --tree=both callgrind.out.3519 | grep baz
```

Or by altering the example:

```
int main(){
  for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++9 {
    foo();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed the --threshold switch in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a 
    clog << "functionname";
in every function. Would kill your performance, but that is what logging is for.

If you want to keep track of calling, i would rather recommend commenting and building doxygen doku, which can generate you caller-graphs as long as there are no function pointers.

If that doesn't fit you, we should know what exactly you need that logging for.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to do this without modifying the existing code base. Could you give me a pointer to the second solution that you suggested above?